# slowing down / animating a table reveal in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am revealing a html table with my JS. At the moment the table kind of pops up instantly. its a bit sharp. is there a way to slow down or make the reveal a bit smoother somehow? its not really a problem but more of a nice to have. is there any kind of simple enough way to add a smoother effect then just the sharp reveal that i currently have?

```
function show_table() {
    //alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    if (document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display === "none") {
      document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display = "table";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of animation are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You could give each `<tr>` an `opacity:0` and then use `transition` with `transition-delay` to fade the rows in one by one. You can use javascript to give each row its own transition delay.